# Why would you `check()` client side Blaze templates data arguments?

Tags: security, meteor, meteor-blaze, javascript-injection

I very well understand why you would `check()` methods and publications arguments serverside, but why would you need to when the data is on client side, considering it could be tampered with at every level?

I saw that is someone else's code, and I wish to know if there is a good reason for it.

For instance:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function() {

  check(this.data.arg1, String);
  check(this.data.arg2, String);

  this.subscribe('mysub', this.data.arg1);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (should) do that in order to

- enforce consistent behavior after a refactoring session (errors will be thrown if you changed names or types of the template input)
- enforce required Template data when you work together with other developers so they get errors when feeding your template with wrong inputs
- enforce required Template data when you create many complex Templates that interact with each other, basically the same as the point above
- create a first input filter on the client side, for example when this Template is requiring user input as a parameter for it's subscription ( Note, that this is not a security feature but it can improve UX)

Use this in combination with your UI tests in order to reveal bugs after code changes and make your UI more robust.

Of course you could leave the `check` out and let the errors to be thrown in the component's code somewhere else but with this you can isolate bugs immediately on the creation level.

Comment: It makes sense, especially the first 2 points. I think the third one is very dependent on the scale of the project (even if you can never be too prepared for success). While I already enforce the fourth point but not at a template level, it is, I guess, a matter of which approach is deemed to be the best, so it is still valid. Thanks for you answer :-)